# simple form selecting multiple options from an array

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I've been working on a rails application and have been trying to get an option created that allows for multiple options to be selected from an array.

Up till now i've only done one option selected vs multiple, and i think that is what is causing my issue.

My form code looks like

```
  = f.input :amenities, label: 'Amenities', required: true, hint: " PRAY THIS WORKS!! " do
    = f.select :amenities, BuildingEnhancements::AMENITIES_LIST.collect { |list| list }, { selected: @property.amenities }, :'data-placeholder' => 'Select amenities type', multiple: true
```

My amenities list looks like

```
  AMENITIES_LIST = [
    'Elevator',
    'Rooftop',
    'Deck',
    'Gym',
    'Bike Racks',
    'Air Conditioning'
  ].freeze
```

All i'm able to see so far is just my array.

Would anyone have any ideas as to what i can do with this guy here?

Comment: When asking, grammar is very important. Please fix your capitalization. "rails" -> "Rails", "i' --> "I". SO is like an online reference book where grammar matters. See the second bullet in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I think multple select can be done with javascript and in rails pass multiple selected value.